# Does Office add-ins work with javascript modules?

Tags: javascript, office365, office-js, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I was working on changing an existing add-in to implement JavaScript modules. But with the changes to my function file, the `ExecuteFunction` action declared in my manifest doesn't work anymore.

Manifest:

```
<Item id="credit/en-CA">
  <Label resid="enCreditEnveloppeButtonLabel"/>
  <Supertip>
    <Title resid="enCreditEnveloppeSuperTipTitle"/>
    <Description resid="paneSubjectSuperTipDescription"/>
  </Supertip>
  <Icon>
    <bt:Image size="16" resid="icon16"/>
    <bt:Image size="32" resid="icon32"/>
    <bt:Image size="80" resid="icon80"/>
  </Icon>
  <Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
    <FunctionName>addEnveloppe</FunctionName>
  </Action>
</Item>
```

Before function file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function addEnveloppe(event){
        console.log(event.id); //This is logged
    }
</script>
```

After function file:

```
<script type="module">
    function addEnveloppe(event){
        console.log(event.id); //The function is never called
    }
</script>
```

I've found some solution using react and node, but I don't want to create an whole other project and change the existing code to work with react. [Here is the example](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-Addin-TaskPane-React)

How can I make my function file with JavaScript modules work? I've also tried exporting the `addEnveloppe` function, but it also doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

In general, the control used to host add-ins is a webview control and does not have all the same capabilities as a full browser.  Some things that work in the browser will not work in this control.  I can't say exactly if this is one of them, but it wouldn't surprise me.

When using the 'yo office' command to create a project (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/yeoman-generator-overview) you can choose the basic taskpane template option with Outlook as it's host and the generated project will include a taskpane and a command (execute function) example to work with.  You'll notice in that case that it doesn't try to embed the function in the HTML file, but rather it will put the function (addEnveloppe in your case) in a separate js/ts file that is referenced in the HTML (via webpack in the output).  The webview control is able to load the referenced code file when running the command and that same file could be imported to other code files as a module.

Comment: So If I have a existing add-in and I'm trying to migrate it to modules, I should create a new one using 'yo office' or integrate webpack in my project?

Comment: You don't have to use webpack or start from a new project.  You could just create the js file, move your code to it, link to it in the html file, and then deploy the js file alongside the html file like you are already doing.

Comment: That is what I tried, but when modifying my JavaScript file type to "module" instead of "text/javascript" the method is not called from the xml file anymore...

Comment: The example shows the JS imbedded in the HTML even after you're changes.  When you are using a separate js file then you don't have the script inside the tag in the HTML.  Instead you have '<script type="text/javascript" src="functions.js"></script>' and the file 'functions.js' contains the script code.

Comment: I know, but I only made it look like that so it could be readable and I could only show some part of the code... But I've tried both ways with a sript tag to my file '<script type="module" src="functions.js"></script>' and with the embeded code and when the type of the script is set to "module", it doesn't work...

Comment: Is there a particular reason you need the tag in html to use the type "module" instead of "text/javascript"?

Answer (score -2):

The example you point to is the repo used to generate projects using the 'yo office' command.  The same thing in basic typescript and html can be seen in https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-Addin-TaskPane including the commands aspect of it.